# Hibernate+SQLServer / Batch insert only the new records

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, batch-insert

I'm trying, using Hibernate 4.3 and SQL-Server 2014, to perform batch insert into a table for only the entities that are not already stored.
I have created a simple table with a primary key definded to ignore duplicate keys

```
create table items 
(
    itemid uniqueidentifier not null, 
    itemname nvarchar(30) not null, 
)
alter table items add constraint items_pk primary key ( itemid ) with ( ignore_dup_key = on );
```

Trying to perform a batch insert through the StatelessSession insert method, the batch insert may fail if one or more entities are already stored into the database table: Hibernate throws a StaleStateException:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.insert(StatelessSessionImpl.java:123)
    at it.test.testingestion.HibernateStatelessSessionPersisterImpl.persistData(HibernateStatelessSessionPersisterImpl.java:18)
    at it.test.testingestion.App.main(App.java:76)
```

When the batch statements are completed Hibernate performs a check over the returned rows count that is different than the expected due to the ignore duplicate keys.

With JDBC, performing a batch insert using a prepared statement, the entities that are already stored into the destination table are skipped but the new entities are saved correctly.

How is it possible to configure Hibernate to perform batch insert ignoring the existing data or wihout performing a check of the affected rows?

Thanks a lot

**Update #1**

As workaround, to force the number of rows affected even if a duplicated insert occurs, I have created the following Hibernate Interceptor:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8022068618978801796L;

    private String getTemporaryTableName() {
        String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        return "##" + currentThreadName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\_]", "");
    }

    private void createTemporaryTable(Connection connection) {
        String tempTableName = this.getTemporaryTableName();
        String commandText = String.format("if (object_id('tempdb.dbo.%s') is null) begin create table [%s] ( dummyfield int ); insert into %s ( dummyfield ) values ( 0 ) end ", tempTableName, tempTableName, tempTableName);
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(commandText)) {
            statement.execute();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("An error has been occurred trying to create the temporary table %s", tempTableName), e);
        }
    }

    public CustomInterceptor(Connection connection) {
        this.createTemporaryTable(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        int ps = sql.toLowerCase().indexOf("insert into ");
        if (ps == 0) {
            String tableName = this.getTemporaryTableName();
            return sql + "; if (@@rowcount = 0) update [" + tableName + "] set dummyfield = 1"; 
        }
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }

}
```

The interceptor, when a new instance is created, creates a new temporary table inserting a new record. 
When an insert statement is intercepted, an update of the record saved into the instanced temporary table is performed if no rows has been affected by the insert statement: this tricks Hibernate about the returned rows event if a duplicate entity is inserted and no StatelessSessionImpl exception is thrown.

Obviously the downside of the trick is the cost to perform the extra update for each row that is not inseted into the table.

Does anyone knows a better way, that does not affect the insert performances, to insert entities into a table thats ignore the duplicate entries using Hibernate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, I would prefer using JDBCBatchUpdate

Approach 1:

As you are filtering the new records, the number of records will not be a constraint. So you could specify an association mapping in the entity layer and could perform a Hibernate batch insert or JDBC Batch update.

Approach 2:
Using Native SQl Query

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
//get Connction from Session
session.doWork(new Work() {
       @Override
       public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
          PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
          try{
           String sqlInsert = "insert into tbl(name) values (?) ";
           pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert );
           int i=0;
           for(String name : list){
               pstmt .setString(1, name);
               pstmt .addBatch();

               //20 : JDBC batch size
             if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { 
                pstmt .executeBatch();
              }
              i++;
           }
           pstmt .executeBatch();
         }
         finally{
           pstmt .close();
         }                                
     }
});
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But, in a large entity-model scenario, use the JDBC approach, imply the re-coding of the persistence layer offered by Hibernate, including listeners, evners and so on. 

For performance reason Is it possible to use the native SQL-Bulkcopy APIs also, but with the same issues as use the JDBC approach.